# Is there a way to include the react-select dropdown near the body tag

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-select

I have react-select included in my react application which is using react-bootstrap.

So I have a bootstrap modal, and the react select inside it, the problem is that the modal body is set to overflow auto, and the react select dropdown now instead of overlapping the modal, actually produces a scroll and is partially hidden.

Is there any way I can ask the options list to render outside the bootstrap modal (while the react-select input sits inside the modal)?

[React select dropdown inside modal (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiOxp.png)

Comment: Try increasing z-index to a react-select.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing this works:

*For the style:*

```
    menuPortal: (provided) => ({
        ...provided,
        zIndex: 9999,
    }),
```

*On the component:*

```
    menuPortalTarget={document.body}
```